# What are these little functions in FFFF**** addres space seen by C# code x86 disassembly?

Tags: c#, clr, disassembly

While debugging some of my code written in C# I had to walk through disassembly to get a clearer understanding of what is going on on a microlevel. Most of the code is rather transparent, but there are some functions obviously provided by CLR or C#, because I didn't implement them, which lie in 0xffff**** address space and are unknown to me. For instance in `Bitmap.Width` there is a call for FFFF0630:

```
00000000  push        ebp 
00000001  mov         ebp,esp 
00000003  push        eax 
00000004  xor         eax,eax 
00000006  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax 
00000009  mov         eax,dword ptr [ecx+10h] 
0000000c  mov         edx,ecx 
0000000e  push        eax 
0000000f  push        edx 
00000010  lea         ecx,[ebp-4] 
00000013  call        FFFF0630
```

I can't step into it with a debugger, so I can only presume from the context, it should be for some kind of memory validation. But I am not sure, as even this functions' tween `Bitmap.Height` has another address FFFF060C at the same spot. There is not much sense in different validation for two almost equivalent properties.

So, what are these functions indeed? What do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't step into it with a debugger

Do you have native debugging enabled? .NET uses the underlying Win32 functions for OS services. It is probably a call into a native DLL.

> has another address FFFF060C

Two ways to find out what libraries are loaded by address:

1. Modules view in Visual Studio (menu: Debug | Windows | Modules).
2. Process Explorer's View | Lower Pane View | Dlls (you might need to add the base address column).

The address a DLL is loaded will depend on OS, 32/64bit, ASLR, and the preferred base address in the DLL.

It is common for system DLLs to be loaded high in the process's address space.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't thought of that. There's nothing past 752D3000 though, but knowing it is not a DLL call still helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find System.Drawing [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing), that where `Bitmap` resides. It inherits from `Image`, which contains both `Height` and `Width`. They look like this:

```
public int Height {
    get {
        uint height;            
        Status status = GDIPlus.GdipGetImageHeight (nativeObject, out height);      
        GDIPlus.CheckStatus (status);           

        return (int)height;
    }
}
public int Width {
    get {
        uint width;         
        Status status = GDIPlus.GdipGetImageWidth (nativeObject, out width);        
        GDIPlus.CheckStatus (status);           

        return (int)width;
    }
}
```

They both call `GDIPlus.CheckStatus` so that's what they have in common.